# Connect Exception with Java Chat Room

Tags: java, chatroom

I have created a chat room using Java. When I run it on just one computer, which isn't necessarily chatting, but testing rather, it runs fine. However, when I run it on a second computer, the program connects but when the second computer user sends a message, it throws a ConnectException error, saying that the connection has been reset.

Any ideas why I might be getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you observe the packets on the wire?  [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) may be invaluable for debugging this.  Also, if you would provide a sample of code that you're using to create this chatroom, that'd help get you faster help.